# JMeterのBSF PreProcessorの挙動について

Tags: javascript, java

Webアプリの負荷テストをするために、JMeterでテスト計画を作っているのですが、
WebアプリのPOSTデータでUUIDをランダムにPOSTする必要があるため、BSF PreProcessorでUUIDをランダム生成し、POSTの中で使おうとしています。

複数回のHTTPリクエストで同じUUIDを使ってPOSTしてほしいのですが、なぜかPreProcessorが何度も実行されているようで、UUIDがHTTPリクエスト毎に変わってしまう問題にぶち当たりました。

テスト計画の構成は

```
スレッドグループ
－Pre Processor（この中でJavaScriptを使ってUUIDをランダム生成しvars.putでパラメータ化。パラメータ名は連番を与える）
－ユーザーパラメータ（ユーザー毎の値を設定。authkeyなど）
－HTTPリクエスト（JSONをPOST。ここで連番のパラメータ名のUUIDを使う。）
－ループコントローラ
－－HTTPリクエスト（上記のPOSTに関連したJSONをPOST。この際に同じUUIDを使う。ループのカウントで連番のパラメータ名を指定）
```

です。
ループ内のUUIDが変わってしまうため、POSTデータの関連性が失われてWebアプリのテストが正常に行えないのです。

UUIDを最初のリクエストで全部投げて、以降のループでUUID毎に１つずつ詳細内容をPOSTするため、パラメータ名は連番です。（例：UUID1, UUID2....）
なのでユーザーパラメータで${__UUID()}を使って羅列するのは非常に厳しいです。

ググってみても、Pre Processorの挙動について書かれた記事が見当たりません。
どなたか解決策を知っている方、教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

BSF PreProcessorをBSF Samplerに変えたらどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Samplerに変えることで一度きりの生成が出来ました。
Pre Processorという名前と公式Docの"applied before taking a sample."という文言に騙された感じです・・・。
せめて"applied before taking the respective samples."とされていたらPre Processorを使わなかったかもしれません。


今回のことから
BSF Sampler : **一度きり**の処理（サンプリング）
BSF Pre Processor : **各**サンプリングの前に実行される処理
という挙動のようですね。

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメントとしては、[4.7 Pre-Processor Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#preprocessors)からリンクされている、[4.10 Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)に以下のようにあります。

- JMeterのテスト計画を構成する要素は、 主に ordered (順列的) (controller と sampler) であると考えられるものと、 hierarchical (階層的) (それ以外) なものに分類できる

  > Some elements in the test trees are strictly hierarchical (Listeners, Config Elements, Post-Procesors, Pre-Processors, Assertions, Timers), and some are primarily ordered (controllers, samplers).

  - Pre-Processorは、種別としては hierarchical である
- hierarchical な要素は、その親要素に属するすべてのリクエストに適用される

  > If its parent is a Controller, then it affects all requests that are descendants of that Controller.
- 各リクエストを処理する時には、テスト計画のツリーを自分の位置から根っこまで親から親へと辿っていき、訪問した要素に属する configuration (hierarchical) 要素を集めて適用する、と考えると分かりやすい

  > imagine each Request being passed up the tree branches, to its parent, then to its parent's parent, etc, and each time collecting all the configuration elements of that parent

このセクションにテスト計画の例があるほか、[4.9 Execution Order](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)にも実行順の例があります:

以下のテスト計画があったとすると

- Controller

  - Post-Processor 1
  - Sampler 1
  - Sampler 2
  - Timer 1
  - Assertion 1
  - Pre-Processor 1
  - Timer 2
  - Post-Processor 2

以下のように実行される:

```
Pre-Processor 1
Timer 1
Timer 2
Sampler 1
Post-Processor 1
Post-Processor 2
Assertion 1

Pre-Processor 1
Timer 1
Timer 2
Sampler 2
Post-Processor 1
Post-Processor 2
Assertion 1
```